# 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python and want to format a date so I can stick it into a sql statement.

Here is my attempt:

```
from datetime import datetime

date = '2012-01-01 12:44'

print date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

And I get:
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Tried a few different ways, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

--EDIT--
Here is the code after the comments and help below:

```
from datetime import datetime

dateString = '2012-01-01 12:44'

date = datetime.strptime(dateString, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

print date
```

Also I was using BeautifulSoup and the field I was using still had the tags around it. (which caused the NavigableString issue. To get around it take the field as simply to a .string to it, before you try to make it a date.

Comment: Are you sure about the error and the line of code you provided? Your snippet should give you an `AttributeError` since you are calling `strftime` on a string. What is the format you want the date to be? The way you are going about it, you will end up truncating the minute part from the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access an attribute called `strftime` of a `NavigableString` object (`'2012-01-01 12:44'` is a string literal in Python), but strings do not have this attribute, so you are getting an exception.

You first need to convert your string into a `datetime.datetime` object, perhaps by using the [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) method:

```
date_obj = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Then you can call the `strftime` attribute on this object:

```
print date_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

Comment: @BurhanKhalid You're right, the original code imported datetime directly ! I've updated my suggestion.

Comment: In addition the OP is using beautifulsoup (that's where `NavigableString` comes from), so you would need to cast the object to a string first.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Casting to a string is exactly what the hold up was, and as mentioned I get also get the value error which as fixed by following the detail in this post.